# InfoPath form gives error on activation in site collection

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, infopath

I am working with InfoPath form with code behind i.e VSTA and encounter `Cannot publish the following form template: TestForm.xsn. Check events log for details.` while activating the form on the site collection from the Central Admin.

What would be the cause?